# What makes randint different from randbelow?

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

From 'import secrets' and 'import random' in Python, what makes those two methods different from each other? I know that randbelow from secrets offer better security, but what makes it so? If I were just making a simple program for myself and I want to generate a random number, would it be unusual to use 'secrets.randbelow()'?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Don't forget to accept an answer (tick the check-mark next to it) and up-vote it, if it answers your question. Doing so stops your question from showing up unanswered in the searches, and it's much better than leaving a comment on the answer saying _thanks_. – Since you're starting out here, also take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [what's on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and read [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put, the key difference is in how the modules generate a seed number. Random's seed is decided by pretty much just the current time, so if I knew/guessed the exact millisecond you ran your program, I would be able to work out all of your outputs. Secrets uses a lot more, and looks at different things depending on what Operating System your computer uses (eg.Windows/Mac/Linux), but are practically impossible to guess.

Comment: You're welcome! Hope you make some good projects with your new knowledge. :-)